# MYSQL: select denied

Tags: mysql

I have a user with full permissions to all my databases yet when I try to run a query it gives me this error:

```
SELECT command denied to user...
```

does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Have you tried a flush privileges ?

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR user@yourhost;`

Comment: Trying to flush privileges but get: `#1227 - Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation`

Comment: Trying to show grants gives me the error: `#1044 - Access denied for user to database 'mysql'`

Comment: How to set previleges with mysql db in godaddy server. i don't find any option to set previleges. How and where we have to set?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the domain your user is associated with does not have permissions.

user@localhost is different from user@% and can be assigned different permissions.